# How can i upload my app to backend in google app engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Right now i use php on google app engine  , by folling this tutorial http://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2009/run-php-on-the-google-app-engine/ ,

But in front execution time limit is 60 seconds, So i learned that i need to upload my app in backend for unlimitted exection time.How can i upload it in backend,Any help please.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can only use Python or Java with AppEngine Backends.

Check out the documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview

Comment: Quercus PHP is Java, essentially

Comment: Touché. Then Google's documentation on that site should still apply.